# json.dumps() won't return... not even after minutes

Tags: python, embedded-linux, iot, gateway, lora

I have a LoRa gateway that runs Linux and it can handle Python apps. I'm using a Python file provided by the manufacturer. It mimics a simple node-RED app. Details can be found [here](https://github.com/russmin/Node-Red-Python/).

Messages are received by the gateway in order, but the problem is that the `json.dumps()` method won't want to return after the call. I figured this out with putting `print()` functions into the original code.

Here is the important part of the code. The point is that the `onMessage()` function gets called when there is an uplink from an endpoint device and the `onMessage()` calls the `rbPayloadFormatters()`. I have never seen the result of the `print(self.packet)` line. When I let the `rbPayloadFormatters()` function return with the `newMsg` dictionary, I was able to see its content, printed from the `onMessage()` function.

```
### formats the payload message from the endpoint
def rbPayloadFormatters(self, msg):
    msgObj = json.loads(msg)
    newMsg = {}
    msgHex = base64.b64decode(msgObj["data"])
    newMsg["payload"] = binascii.hexlify(msgHex)
    newMsg["time"] = msgObj["tmst"]
    newMsg["snr"] = msgObj["lsnr"]
    newMsg["station"] = msgObj["appeui"]
    newMsg["avgsnr"] = msgObj["lsnr"]
    newMsg["lat"] = 0
    newMsg["lng"] = 0
    newMsg["rssi"] = msgObj["rssi"]
    newMsg["seqnumber"] = msgObj["seqn"]
    newMsg["deveui"] = msgObj["deveui"]
    newMsg["authorisation"] = self.rbAuthorization
    return json.dumps(newMsg)

#callback function initiated by on_message
def onMessage(self, mqtt_client, userdata, msg):
    self.packet = self.rbPayloadFormatters(msg.payload)
    pkt = json.loads(self.packet)
    self.devEUI = pkt["deveui"]
    self.payloadData = pkt["payload"]
    
    print(self.packet)
```

I have read that the stdlib `json.dumps()` can be slow but after minutes of waiting I was not able to see any printed `json` object on the console.

If you have any idea what is wrong, please don't hesitate to answer to this post. Thank you.

Comment: You could try to comment out some of the lines which add keys to `newMsg` to narrow the problem down to one or two specific keys.

Comment: I don't see any reason why `json.dumps` would take a long time here, unless the data is enormous.  As there seems to be networking involved I'd be suspicious that somewhere a socket might be be waiting for part of a message that never arrives (but that's a guess)

Comment: What is `self.rbAuthorization`? Every other value (aside from the literal `0`s) comes from an existing JSON object, so that would seem to be the only thing that could cause a problem for `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I continued the debugging and first tried Michael Butscher’s advice and started to comment out lines which add keys to `newMsg`.

Turned out that the `json.dumps()` returns and the `rbPayloadFormatters()` returns as well if I comment out the next two lines.

```
msgHex = base64.b64decode(msgObj["data"])
newMsg["payload"] = binascii.hexlify(msgHex)
```

The explanation for the never returning `json.dumps()` is the data type of the `msgHex` and `newMsg["payload"]`. Both of them has type bytes and json doesn’t support this type. (I think, I should have received an error… but I didn’t.)

To solve my problem I simply converted the `msgHex` to string.

```
newMsg["payload"] = str(binascii.hexlify(msgHex))
```

Thank you everyone for the contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Supporting [Michael Butscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987358/michael-butscher) and [snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb)'s comments this does not seem to be a problem with the `json` library.

I did some small-scale testing and tried to dump a dictionary equaling about 300 megabytes of data, which took around 5.5 seconds on average.

Code:

```
import json
import time

start = time.time()
data = {i:0 for i in range(10_000_000)}

print("size of object (Bytes):", data.__sizeof__())

j = json.dumps(data)

print("time to dump: ", time.time() - start)
```

Out:

```
size of object (Bytes): 335544384
time to dump:  5.49969482421875
```

Note that this won't be representative of more complex real-world data.

In my personal experience `json.dumps` has been slow at times, but not nearing minute-long wait times (at least for moderate amounts of data).

I would recommend having a look at Python [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html), which will provide a quick report of where and what your code is spending time doing.

Example from the docs:

```py
import cProfile
import re
cProfile.run('re.compile("foo|bar")')
```

Out:

```
      214 function calls (207 primitive calls) in 0.002 seconds

Ordered by: cumulative time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 <string>:1(<module>)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 __init__.py:250(compile)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 __init__.py:289(_compile)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _compiler.py:759(compile)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _parser.py:937(parse)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _compiler.py:598(_code)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _parser.py:435(_parse_sub)
```

With the details you have provided it seems like loading the original message in `rbPayloadFormatters` with `msgObj = json.loads(msg)` doesn't take a long time, as 'json.loads' is usually equally or more time intensive than `json.dumps`, which tells me that the issue lies elsewhere.

Hope this was of help, and good luck with further debugging!

Comment: I am currently experiencing around 25 times longer waits when using json.dumps in the debugger. A fairly standard wait without debugging.

Comment: Read somewhere else that the issue was in the decoder/encoder. If you use non-default options, try removing them.